# Allowing for some Nonlinear Constraint Violations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem with a non-negativity constraint (which has to be translated with a minus sign below). The constraint is given by:

```
function
[neg_constraint,zero_con]=metric_con_130830(theta,v_b,spec,selector,time_all,lambda_all)
theta=exp(theta);
g_sum=selector*(lambda_all*theta.*time_all);
%minus v_b-g_sum because I want v_b-g_sum to be positive
neg_constraint=-(v_b-g_sum);
zero_con=[];
```

I don't mind if the constraint is violated sometimes. In particular, I don't mind if 20% (or some other number) of entries in the vector (v_b-g_sum) are negative. Any ideas how to get that in my code efficiently?

A quick fix would be to do this:

```
zero_con=sum((v_b-g_sum)<0)./length(g_sum)>.20
```

but I wonder how well the optimizer will find a minimum with this indicator function which is not very smooth.

Alternatively, I could take a random sample (size of which is 80%) and check the constraint that way:

```
zero_con=v_b-g_sum;
zero_con=zero_con(randsample(length(zero_con),round(.8*(length(zero_con)))));
```

Comment: I'd guess if matlab just ignore points that get outside non linear region. So, I'd say if you accept some percentage of bounds violation you will get the exact behavior you want, but you risk your answer being 20% outside bound after convergence, since the last check will also be validated through that condition. What I would do is: after the convergence in this conditions you proposed, I'd add one more optimization after the less constrained algorithm to force convergence to the closest accepted minimum.

Comment: You could also add a smoothing factor that increases as convergences grows, by checking the iteration number, or the error decrease rate, i.e: `acceptance_rate = (current_iter_delta_err/mean_first_10_err)*scale_factor` is your acceptance of non linear boundary break. `scale_factor` is a parameter to adjust the percentage to reasonable levels. You could also add a limit threshold, if `acceptance_rate<0.02, acceptance_rate = 0` to ensure convergence to inbound solutions.

Comment: I like this last suggestion. That seems very sensible. Thank you, Werner.

Comment: You're welcome. Please send feedback if you test it, I'd like to know if it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, adding some randomness to the constraint function is a bad plan - the optimiser has no chance... it will think it has found something close to a solution, and next time it tries something close to it, the solution will have completely changed.

You're right that it will hurt the convergence of the optimiser if you have a single function that returns the proportion of constraints that are satisfied, because it will not be smooth - it is a discrete function that will jump in steps. Furthermore, you're effectively hiding useful information from the optimiser, because it doesn't know how individual constraints are affected by the solution parameters.

I suggest you add an additional unknown, say `conval`, and instead of testing whether the constraints are <0, test whether they are less than `conval`. Each of these would be returned as separate constraints, giving the optimiser full knowledge of how the constraints can be changed by inputs.

Then add an additional constraint:

```
if (number of constraints broken < 20%)
    return 0
else
    return (smallest constraint violation)^2
```

So say you've got 100 constraints, and 20 of them are violated, we're ok. Then as the 21st slides into being violated, you start returning the square of the amount that 21st is violating the constraint. Since it is a square, it will smoothly increase from zero as the constraint comes into play. As the inputs change, it won't always be the same constraint that is the smallest - it could switch to another one, but at least there won't be a jump as it switches between the two (just a jump in derivative).

Comment: Thanks, Pancake. I will give this a try. In the meantime I have found a work around but this sounds like a sensible plan.